# Display the column IDs for a column having same dates

Tags: list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a list with date column.

Items having the same dates should store the IDs together.

For eg: Item ID 1,12,15,etc. has the same date,then a column in these items should store all these IDs.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with an Item Added Event Receiver which would update all the other Items with the same Date. I don't see any other option if the list is still changing.

Reference on how to add an Event Receiver
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx

Pseudo Code:
if list contains other Item with same Date
write this to this and the other item

If you want to do this for a list which will not have any further changes you could do this by using a powershell script which iterates trough all list items and edits the items with the same dates.